# not able to click a link with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have an button and am not sure the best way to grab it and need suggestions.

i have tried
'''
driver.find_elements(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value='MLB').click()
'''
but that doesnt work

```
    <a rel="nofollow" class="text-capitalize sports-scroll-menu__draggable__item__link slider- 
    home-item item_featured_menu " href="javascript:void(0)" data-type="featured" data- 
    section="fd" data-zone="home-tabs-featured" data-name="MLB" data-league="5" data- 
    breadcrumb="1885_200">MLB</a>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "but that doesnt work". What is the webpage you are scraping?

Comment: It would help to see the surrounding html. Is it just the one link you are trying to click?

Comment: .find_elements should be .find_element

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: whats the url? you may not even need selenium